# Octave gives the error unable to open X11 Display, when trying to plot graphs

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, octave, x11

When attempting to plot graphs in python 2.7 using matplotlib or Octave the program stalls and needs to be closed. Octave gives the following errors on startup:

No protocol specified
octave: unable to open X11 DISPLAY
octave: disabling GUI features
No protocol specified

If I run plot(x,y) the program stalls and on pressing Ctrl-C the following appears.

gnuplot: unable to open display ':0'
gnuplot: X11 aborted.

I have tried many online suggestions such as setting X11Forwarding to yes (which it already was), and running startx which leaves me with a blank screen with a cross cursor and changing DISPLAY to numerous things, among others.

OS: Ubuntu 16.10 
Processor: AMD A10-8700P Radeon R6

UPDATE:
When I run xinit I get the following:

(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 0
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X0-lock
    and start again.
(EE) 
(EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
(EE) 
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 7 requests (7 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

Not sure why I would need this or if it helps. Also in octave if I run 'setenv("DISPLAY")' then try to run a plot it still stalls but on canceling the terminal shows a blank screen with the forward, back and quit commands.

This is a new system and haven't had these problems with octave or python before.

Comment: are you using SSH to login on another computer and run Octave? What does `echo $DISPLAY` return?

Comment: No I am not using SSH to login to another computer, was desperate so tried ssh related solutions. echo $DISPLAY returns :0.

Comment: "how to set up X11" is not really a programming question, but anyway, try running on your local computer as the same user that logs in to the X11 session. If this doesn't work, try running some X11-based program like xterm from the terminal. Data about these attempts and exact error messages you get are critical.

Comment: xterm opens normally no errors. I am not familiar with X11 sessions but I am logged into my computer under the account I usually use. Also where would this post be more appropriate?

Comment: I made updates to the question, with some more errors I am getting.